Toggle evaluation of geometry node on another object during editing
tl;dr: is there a way to turn off/on all modifiers (or modifiers for a specific object) while I'm in edit mode on a different object?
Object A is a curve; object B is a dummy mesh using a Geometry Nodes modifier to perform complex calculations using A. Having the modifier enabled while editing A is too slow; it takes 5 seconds just to select a single control point, and attempting to move the control point updates the screen once every few seconds. So, I select B, go to its modifiers, and disable its modifier. With B's modifier disabled, editing is an easy process. However, I occasionally need to re-enable the modifier to check some results.
Right now this involves leaving edit mode, selecting B, changing its modifier, selecting A, and entering edit mode again. That's cumbersome. I wish that just hiding B in the viewport would stop its modifier from being evaluated, but that's not the case.


Add an area for the Python Console
Create a variable representing the modifier using
mod = bpy.data.objects.get("ObjectBName").modifiers[0]
(assumes the modifier is the first/only)
To toggle the evaluation of the modifier, run this line in the console:
mod.show_viewport = not mod.show_viewport

You can use up-arrow in the console to bring up the last command. So, after you type that last command in once, each additional time you want to toggle the visibility, move the cursor over the Console viewport, and press ↑ enter and the modifier will toggle evaluation/display.


If you enable the default addon Modifier Tools it has an operator to disable all modifiers on an object. Basically achieving this effect but on all mods, with additional tools as well.

@Jakemoyo Reading up on this it seems that it only can control the selected objects. If I'm editing a separate object, I can't select Object B, right? (Forgive my noob question, I assume this is true because the Properties panel does not switch to show me the modifiers for Object B when I select it in the Outliner panel.) If I'm wrong, this seems like another good answer you could supply.

Yeah, generally speaking any operator thats been converted to a tool will work around the context its in. Not all but quite frequently this is the case. Your script is operating on the data itself by getting the object through bpy.data.objects and getting its modifier etc. That works outside the context generally.
